# The ODE $y''(x)=\sinh(x)-3y'(x)-2y(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I am trying to solve the differential equation that is in the title as a System of first order ode.

My Approach:
$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\begin{array}{c} y \\ y' \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} y' \\ \sinh(x)-3y'-2y \end{array}\right)=$
$\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 \\ 
-2 & -3 \\
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} y \\ y' \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ \sinh(x) \end{array}\right)$

Then I calculate the characteristic polynomial of the coefficient matrix, which leads to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-2,\lambda_2=-1$. Let A denote the matrix above.
Calculating the matrix exponential, I get $e^{Ax}$=$\frac{1}{e^{2x}} \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
2e^x-1 & e^x-1 \\ 
-2e^x+2 & -e^x+2 \\
\end{array}\right)$

Now I am variating the parameters and get
$y(x)=\frac{1}{e^{2x}} \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
2e^x-1 & e^x-1 \\ 
-2e^x+2 & -e^x+2 \\
\end{array}\right)y_0+\frac{1}{e^{2x}} \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
2e^x-1 & e^x-1 \\ 
-2e^x+2 & -e^x+2 \\
\end{array}\right) \int_0^s  \left(\begin{array}{c} \sinh(x)(e^{-s}-1) \\ \sinh(x)(-e^{-s}+2) \end{array}\right)ds$ =

$y(x)=\frac{1}{e^{2x}} \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
2e^x-1 & e^x-1 \\ 
-2e^x+2 & -e^x+2 \\
\end{array}\right)y_0+\frac{1}{e^{2x}} \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
2e^x-1 & e^x-1 \\ 
-2e^x+2 & -e^x+2 \\
\end{array}\right)  \left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{1}{4}e^{-2x}(e^{2x}(2x+3)-2e^x-2e^{3x}+1+C_1) \\ \frac{-x}{2} -\frac{e^{-2x}}{4}+e^{-x}+e^{x} +C_2\end{array}\right)$

My Questions are: In the exercise description there was no value for $y_0$, is there a way to find the value for it?
Is my calculation correct (does it seem correct) or are there any mistakes?

Comment: This really seems like overkill to me. Just use the standard second-order case and do method of undetermined coefficients ($\sinh$ is just a linear combination of exponentials)

Comment: @StephenDonovan I know, but I just want to try this method out

Comment: Well your first line and your eigenvalues are right...that's as far as I'm going, I hate this technique honestly.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor It's a lot more useful when it comes to solving things numerically, since any higher-order equation can be rewritten as a first-order system. But yeah I agree, for linear equations with constant coefficients it's a bit much to go through

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti shouldn't y(x) be a vector valued function, or am I just confused right now?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti right, well that was a bad naming choice. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite equation as
$$y''+3y'+2y=\frac{e^x}{2}-\frac{e^{-x}}{2}$$
Characteristic equation is
$$\lambda^2+3\lambda + 2=0$$
Then $\lambda_1=-2,\lambda_2=-1$. Solution of $y''+3y'+2y=0$ is
$$y_h=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}$$
For particular solution use method of undetermined coefficients.
$$y_p=Ae^x+Bxe^{-x}$$
We get
$$6Ae^x+Be^{-x}=\frac{e^x}{2}-\frac{e^{-x}}{2}$$
Then $A=\frac{1}{12}, B=-\frac{1}{2}$.
General solution is

$$y=y_h+y_p=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}+\frac{e^x}{12}-\frac{xe^{-x}}{2}.$$

Comment: Only leaving this comment because it took my 30+ minutes to figure this out:
The formulation of $y_p (x)$ is a generic guess based on the right hand side's form.
Obtaining $A e^{x} + B e^{-x} = \frac{e^{x}}{2}-\frac{e^{-x}}{2}$ came from the original ODE and $y_p$, or $y_p '' + 3*y_p ' + 2*y_p = sinh(x) = \frac{e^{x}}{2} - \frac{e^{-x}}{2}$.
Finally, the solution comes from $y(x)=y_h (x) + y_p (x)$

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between this method and the classical one for linear ODE's with constant coefficient. The Eigenvalues are found by solving the characteristic polynomial $$\lambda(\lambda+3)+2$$ while the straight method yields the characteristic polynomial

$$\lambda^2+3\lambda+2.$$
You just get longer computation because you compute $y$ and $y'$ simultaneously.

Alternatively to variation of the coefficients, you can use the known rules for exponential RHS, or indeterminate coefficients based on an ansatz with $\sinh,\cosh$ times first degree polynomials (needed because one root is common with the time constant of an exponential).

---

The value of $y_0$ is a free parameter (there is a solution for any $y_0$), you can't compute it.

Answer (score 0):

We could utilize Duhamel's Integral for this problem. First, I'll write the end goal so that given $y''(x)+a*y'(x)+b*y(x)=g(x)$:

$$y(x)=y_{h}(x)+\int_{0}^{x}u(x-s)*g(s)ds$$

Where $u(x,A,B)=y_{h}(x,c_{1},c_{2})$ is solved for constants $A,B$.

First we observe the characteristic polynomial $y_{c}(\lambda)$ such that:

$$y_{c}(\lambda)=0=\lambda^2+a\lambda+b \implies 0=\lambda^2+3\lambda+2\implies **\lambda \in \lbrace -2 , -1 \rbrace**$$

Each characteristic root is of multiplicity $1$ so our homogenous solution takes the form:

$$y_{h}(x)=c_{1}x^{0}e^{-2x}+c_{2}x^{0}e^{-1x} \implies **y_{h}(x)=c_1e^{-2x}+c_{2}e^{-x}**$$

Now we obtain $u(x)$ with solved constants:

$$u(0)=0=A+B \implies A=-B$$
$$u'(0)=1=-2A-B \implies A=-1 , B=1$$
$$**u(x)=-e^{-2x}+e^{-x}**$$

Now we can form the solution so that:

$$**y(x)=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2e^{-x}+\int^{x}_{0}(-e^{-2(x-s)}+e^{-(x-s)})*(sinh(s))ds**$$

The specifics on this solution can be further explored in *Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems* by Teschl in chapter 3. Because I found it hard enough to learn how to form this solution so that I could be typing it here, I'll leave the actual integration as an exercise. :)